# rearrange order of columns such that a specific column gets the same string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want column 2 to have the string Piebald, the order of the other strings doesn't matter. I have:

```
HR0024  Black pastel    Piebald
HR0028  Piebald
MC0023  Piebald
MC0039  Fire    Piebald
MC0075  Piebald VPI Axanthic
MC0082  Pastel  Piebald
MC0120  Piebald Yellowbelly     Het-Lavender
MC0124  Super-Pastel    Piebald Het-Clown
MC0126  Fire    Pastel  Piebald
MC0144  Piebald Vanilla
```

I want something like this:

```
HR0024 Piebald pastel Black
HR0028 Piebald
MC0023 Piebald
MC0039 Piebald Fire
MC0075 Piebald VPI Axanthic
MC0082 Piebald Pastel
MC0120 Piebald Yellowbelly Het-Lavender
MC0124 Piebald Super-Pastel Het-Clown
MC0126 Piebald Pastel Fire
MC0144 Piebald Vanilla
```

Some rows are going to have the target strings on different columns (2, 3, or 4). I don't think `cut -f` does the job here, I think `awk` or `sed` is needed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your field separator, a tab?

Comment: yes, it was tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With awk, we loop over the fields and if we find the chosen one, we swap with the second field.

```bsh
awk -v p="Piebald" '{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == p) {$i = $2; $2 = p; break}
}1' file
```

- `1` at the end means `print` the line.
- `break` exits early the loop after swapping
- `-v var="value"` is the standard way to pass a variable to `awk`.
- Also, this way, any sequential spaces in the input are shrinking to one space, which is the default output field separator.

Output:

```
HR0024 Piebald pastel Black
HR0028 Piebald
MC0023 Piebald
MC0039 Piebald Fire
MC0075 Piebald VPI Axanthic
MC0082 Piebald Pastel
MC0120 Piebald Yellowbelly Het. lavender
```

Comment: Perfect! I changed the input slightly so that a few spaces weren't treated as different fields (e.g. "Het. lavender" is now "Het-Lavender").

Comment: @Age87 Try it as `awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' -v p="Piebald" ...` to not confuse spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 3):

If the order of the other strings doesn't matter, you can just do:

```
$ sed -E 's/Piebald//g; s/^(\S+)/\1 Piebald/' file 
HR0024 Piebald  Black pastel    
HR0028 Piebald  
MC0023 Piebald  
MC0039 Piebald  Fire    
MC0075 Piebald   VPI Axanthic
MC0082 Piebald  Pastel  
MC0120 Piebald   Yellowbelly     Het-Lavender
MC0124 Piebald  Super-Pastel     Het-Clown
MC0126 Piebald  Fire    Pastel  
MC0144 Piebald   Vanilla
```

Or, if your `sed` doesn't support that:

```
$ perl -pe 's/Piebald//g; s/^(\S+)/\1 Piebald/' file 
HR0024 Piebald  Black pastel    
HR0028 Piebald  
MC0023 Piebald  
MC0039 Piebald  Fire    
MC0075 Piebald   VPI Axanthic
MC0082 Piebald  Pastel  
MC0120 Piebald   Yellowbelly     Het-Lavender
MC0124 Piebald  Super-Pastel     Het-Clown
MC0126 Piebald  Fire    Pastel  
MC0144 Piebald   Vanilla
```